# Ceph s3 LDAP not working despite following instructions

Tags: ldap, ceph, ceph-rgw

I have a problem with LDAP configuration in Ceph. I have a fresh cluster (for testing purposes). No operation has been performed on it except adding certificates to Dashborad and Grafana and issuing . In my architecture, I have a cluster and in front of it a HAProxy that directs traffic to the appropriate nodes that issue S3 and/or Dashboard.

Cluster put on VMs, Rocky9 as OS, all in one VLAN and one subnet. I used the cephadm instructions for bootstrapping the cluster to set up. Instructions: https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/install/ . I am using the latest version of Ceph.

According to the instructions of Ceph and RedHat:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_ceph_storage/2/html-single/ceph_object_gateway_with_ldapad_guide/index
https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/radosgw/ldap-auth/

I should add a few lines to the ceph.conf file and restart the service (which targets all deamons). Yet adding the configuration to the file did not work and after restarting the cluster the configuration returns to its original (minimal) version. Therefore, instead of typing in the file, I executed commands that add the configuration to the ceph configuration database using:

For example:

```
ceph config set global rgw_ldap_dnattr "uid"
```

Despite this, it did not produce the results I expected, as the service still did not want to reload configuration so I found the command that this service executes and ran it manually. The first time I got an additional message about the lack of a "keyring" so I created one. In this keyring, I added permissions (for validation test purposes) for everything as '*'. Of course, I made sure that the client name was correct. Keyring was created on each node that serves S3. Despite this, the service still had a problem to reload (apply) configuration. But warning about keyring was gone during manual execution of command - one step forward.

Nevertheless, the LDAP configuration does not go to the daemons because they do not have LDAP parameters set after listing.

```bash
[root@ceph0-dev ~]# systemctl status  ceph-radosgw.target
● ceph-radosgw.target - ceph target allowing to start/stop all ceph-radosgw@.service instances at once
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ceph-radosgw.target; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active since Fri 2024-03-15 16:36:16 CET; 22s ago
      Until: Fri 2024-03-15 16:36:16 CET; 22s ago

Mar 15 16:36:16 ceph0-dev systemd[1]: Stopped target ceph target allowing to start/stop all ceph-radosgw@.service instances at once.
Mar 15 16:36:16 ceph0-dev systemd[1]: Stopping ceph target allowing to start/stop all ceph-radosgw@.service instances at once...
Mar 15 16:36:16 ceph0-dev systemd[1]: Reached target ceph target allowing to start/stop all ceph-radosgw@.service instances at once.
[root@ceph0-dev ~]# radosgw --show-config | grep ldap
rgw_ldap_binddn = uid=admin,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com
rgw_ldap_dnattr = uid
rgw_ldap_searchdn = cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
rgw_ldap_searchfilter =
rgw_ldap_secret = /etc/openldap/secret
rgw_ldap_uri = ldaps://<ldap.your.domain>
rgw_s3_auth_use_ldap = false
```

Has anyone had a similar problem, can anyone suggest what can be done to make it work?
I did not found any exceptional documentation about problems with LDAP.

Regards,
Konrad